# The Tomcat server is running properly but still error 404 is generated

Tags: java, xml, jsp

[Server working fine but error landing on home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNAOL.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] - a question which consists only of a title and a link to an image is never going to be a good question.

Comment: check web path in server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

of course its an error you cant directly access whats inside WEB-INF folder.change location of your your home.jsp to webcontent folder.
**WEB-INF directory is a private area of the web application, any files under WEB-INF directory cannot be accessed directly from browser**  but if you are using a url mapping in your application server will resolve the path and direct you to the given page even if its within WEB-INF